# XSLT select all text except one child node text

Tags: xslt, select, text, nodes, except

I have xml like this:

```
<article>
   <title> Test title - <literal> Compulsory - </literal> <fn> ABC </fn> 
   <comments> a comment</comments>
   </title>
</article>
```

I want to get all child node + self text in a variable 
e.g.

> *$full_title*   = "Test title - Compulsory - ABC"

```
Except comments node text.
```

Following is my unsuccessful try where i miss title node text.

```
<xsl:template name="test">
    <xsl:variable name="full_title" select="article/title/*[not(self::comments)][1]" />
    <xsl:variable name="width" select="45" /> 
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="string-length($full_title) &gt;    $width">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($full_title,1,$width),'..')"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$full_title"/>    
                    </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `*` to `node()`. That will select both elements and text nodes that are children of the `<title>` element. Then take out the `[1]` since you want *all* children of `<title>`:

```
<xsl:variable name="full_title"
    select="string-join(article/title/node()[not(self::comments)], '')" />
```

A more reliable way to do it, so that you won't get tripped up if you have multiple levels under `<title>` and `<comments>` elements occur as grandchildren, would be this:

```
<xsl:variable name="full_title"
    select="string-join(article/title//text()[not(ancestor::comments)], '')" />
```

## Update:

Since you want the variable to hold a string value, and since you're passing it to functions like `concat()` and `string-length()` which cannot take a sequence of multiple nodes as a first argument, using `string-join(..., '')` around the sequence converts it to a string by concatenating the string values of each node.

Comment: When I remove [1] from "[not(self::comments)][1]" i am facing an error, while transforming xml into html using saxon: ERROR: "A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of <function>". That is why i had to keep [1], but in result i do not get all node text, any suggestion ?

Comment: @Ali: OK, you're right; I forgot about the ways you're using `$full_title`. See my new edit, using `string-join()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="full-text">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[not(self::comments)]" 
               mode="no-comments"/> 
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:value-of select="$full-text"/><!-- just for debug-->
    </xsl:template >

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="no-comments">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

attribute `mode` used only for clarity

Comment: Dewfy, this will select text nodes at all levels, rather than just those inside the `<article><title>`.